# MongoDB question: Using $and and $or queries to read database with 1 $and and multiple $or

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nosql, conditional-statements

Trying to solve the optional task at Codecademy's MongoDB course and unable to solve the 3rd question - In listingsAndReviews, find entries in the borough "Bronx" that serve one of the following cuisines: "Juice, Smoothies, Fruit Salads", "Spanish", or "Pizza". Does a comma separate $and and $or? Please help, thank you!

My solution:

```js
db.listingsAndReviews.find( { $and: [ {borough: "Bronx}, { $or: [cuisine: "Spanish"}, {cuisine: "Juice, Smoothies, Fruit Salads"},{cuisine: "Pizza"}]}]})
```

SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected "," (1:75)

Comment: It looks like you are missing a `{` before the first document in the `$or` arrray, and a `"` after Bronx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `$and` and `$or`. You can solve it with `$in`:

```js
db.listingsAndReviews.find({
  borough: "Bronx",
  cuisine: { $in: ["Spanish", "Juice, Smoothies, Fruit Salads", "Pizza"] }
}
```